# Differences between calculating the relative change and taking the natural log to represent relative change in Stata

Tags: regression, panel-data, stata, logarithm

In a (panel) regression with income as the dependent variable, I would like to estimate the effect of a treatment on the relative change in income. I found two mathematically equivalent ways to do this. Either

- by calculating **relative change = post-treatment income - pre-treatment income / pre-treatment income** and then regressing it on treatment,
- or by taking the natural logarithm of income, i.e. **lninc = ln(income)**, then regressing it on treatment and, finally, calculating exp(Beta_T)-1

However, the results are not the same! Here a stylized example replicating the problem:

```
    clear

    set seed 111
    
    set obs 10000

    gen id = _n
    
    expand 2 // two observations per individual
    
    bysort id: gen t = _n // time
    
    bysort id (t): gen T = (_n==2) // treatment
    
    gen inc = rnormal(10+50000*T,1) // dependent variable

    assert inc > 0 // all values > 0
    
    bysort id: gen relinc = ((inc[_n] - inc[_n-1])/inc[_n-1]) // relative change
    replace relinc = 0 if t==1
    
    gen lninc = ln(inc) 
    
    bysort id: gen lndiff = exp(lninc[2] - lninc[1])-1 
    sum lndiff relinc if relinc != 0 // the relative changes using these two approaches are in fact the same
    
    xtset id t
    qui xtreg relinc T, fe
    margins, dydx(T) // 5061
    
    qui xtreg lninc T, fe
    margins, expression(exp(_b[T])-1) // 5035
```

On real data, the differences can be quite large and sometimes even the sign differs.

How come Stata comes to different conclusions here?

Comment: Since you are using different numbers to represent your data, you ought to be deeply surprised if Stata *did* give the same results: that would be grounds to suspect an error.  What kinds of differences, then, do you want to draw our attention to?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Different numbers of observations? Both regressions run on the same sample. Different numbers as in two different ways to calculate the relative change? As I show in the code snippet, the approaches are mathematically equivalent.

Comment: On the contrary, they are not mathematically equivalent: the relative change is not the same as the logarithm, even though they will *approximately* agree for small changes.  And exponentiating the parameter estimate simply is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log difference is an approximation that [works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/74927/7071) for small changes and quickly degrades, as @whuber already pointed out in the comments. Your change is enormous, so it's no surprise. If you have a smaller change, things look much better, as I show below.

He is also correct on the exponentiation. You can read [this post](http://davegiles.blogspot.com/2011/03/dummies-for-dummies.html) by David Giles for details while I blushingly edit some old answers. I have implemented a less biased solution using `nlcom`. It assumes that once you log the outcome, the errors become normal.

I also tweaked your code in a couple places to use time-series operators, since this is so much better than using relative position.

```
. clear

. set seed 111

. set obs 10000
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 10,000

. gen id = _n

. expand 2 // two observations per individual
(10,000 observations created)

. bysort id: gen t = _n // time

. bysort id (t): gen T = (_n==2) // treatment

. gen inc = rnormal(10+.5*T,1) // dependent variable

. assert inc > 0 // all values > 0

. xtset id T
       panel variable:  id (strongly balanced)
        time variable:  T, 0 to 1
                delta:  1 unit

. gen relinc = D.inc/L.inc // relative change
(10,000 missing values generated)

. replace relinc = 0 if t==1
(10,000 real changes made)

. gen lninc = ln(inc) 

. bysort id: gen lndiff = exp(D.lninc)-1 
(10,000 missing values generated)

. sum lndiff relinc if relinc != 0 // the relative changes using these two approaches are in fact the same

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
      lndiff |     10,000    .0631367    .1494297  -.4465929   .9864048
      relinc |     10,000    .0631367    .1494297  -.4465929    .986405

. qui xtreg relinc T, fe

. margins, dydx(T) // 5061

Average marginal effects                        Number of obs     =     20,000
Model VCE    : Conventional

Expression   : Linear prediction, predict()
dy/dx w.r.t. : T

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      dy/dx   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           T |   .0631367   .0014943    42.25   0.000     .0602079    .0660655
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. xtreg lninc T, fe

Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs     =     20,000
Group variable: id                              Number of groups  =     10,000

R-sq:                                           Obs per group:
     within  = 0.1196                                         min =          2
     between =      .                                         avg =        2.0
     overall = 0.0634                                         max =          2

                                                F(1,9999)         =    1357.76
corr(u_i, Xb)  = 0.0000                         Prob > F          =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       lninc |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           T |   .0514681   .0013968    36.85   0.000     .0487301    .0542061
       _cons |   2.295573   .0009877  2324.23   0.000     2.293637    2.297509
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  .07009358
     sigma_e |  .09876703
         rho |  .33495349   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
F test that all u_i=0: F(9999, 9999) = 1.01                  Prob > F = 0.3579

. nlcom (e_assuming_normal_errors:exp(_b[T] - 0.5*_se[T]^2)-1)

e_assuming~s:  exp(_b[T] - 0.5*_se[T]^2)-1

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   lninc |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
e_assuming_normal_errors |   .0528146   .0014705    35.91   0.000     .0499323    .0556968
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. xtreg inc T, fe

Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs     =     20,000
Group variable: id                              Number of groups  =     10,000

R-sq:                                           Obs per group:
     within  = 0.1209                                         min =          2
     between =      .                                         avg =        2.0
     overall = 0.0641                                         max =          2

                                                F(1,9999)         =    1375.61
corr(u_i, Xb)  = 0.0000                         Prob > F          =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         inc |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           T |   .5231742   .0141059    37.09   0.000     .4955239    .5508245
       _cons |   9.980207   .0099743  1000.59   0.000     9.960655    9.999759
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     sigma_u |  .70835751
     sigma_e |  .99743422
         rho |  .33526336   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
F test that all u_i=0: F(9999, 9999) = 1.01                  Prob > F = 0.3323

. margins, eydx(T)

Average marginal effects                        Number of obs     =     20,000
Model VCE    : Conventional

Expression   : Linear prediction, predict()
ey/dx w.r.t. : T

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |      ey/dx   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           T |   .0511156   .0013804    37.03   0.000       .04841    .0538212
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I also added a third way to calculate an elasticity.

Finally, you may want to review some questions on re-transformation bias. This is something that comes up eventually with logged outcome. I don't want you to have to learn this stuff on the street the hard way.